# radio button value access using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons,How to retrieve the value of selected type using jquery

Regards,
chaitu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this....
 suppose html is this...

```
<label><input type="radio" name="color" value="red" checked="checked" />Red</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="color" value="red" checked="checked" />Blue</label><br />
```

then jquery will be

```
var the_value;
the_value = jQuery('input:radio:checked').val();
alert(the_value);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLRet/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var var_name = $("input[name='your_radio_name']:checked").val();
```